# What does this error mean is wrong?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The server type is Database engine it's local on my laptop and it's in Microsoft SQL server management studio 2014 paid version for personal use only not express I think it was something like £40 so im annoyed it's playing up.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DOUGLAS-LAPTOP.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: Try typing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `.` (period) into the "Server name" textbox when connecting.

Comment: Are you sure the service is running? Check services dialog.

Comment: Wanna have a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci/35673211#35673211

Comment: Open your services (windows key -> services or 'view local services') and make sure that SQL Server is running

Comment: What is your connection string? I have a sinking feeling you are attaching a database file instead of connecting directly to the server.

Comment: @Moumit was that completely necessary? Guy's just bought some software and can't get it to work. I'd be annoyed too.

Comment: If it cost you £40, then you have the "Developer Edition". This is for non-production use only, but has all of the same features as the "Enterprise Edition" (which costs over 14,000 USD per core). (A pity you paid for it though; as of this month it is free.)

Comment: I got it over a year ago its only as of a few days ago it started having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets make this a wiki answer. Things to check:

1. Open your services (windows key -> services or 'view local services') and make sure that SQL Server is running
2. Try typing localhost or 127.0.0.1 or . (period) into the "Server name" textbox when connecting.